# jQuery colliding with another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

So basically what I am trying to do is write is a cart for my website, I have a dropdown cart and a checkout both uses the same classes i.ex. `.quantity` for the quantity and `.price` for the price.

I tried to re-write the code to work with a `<select>` and with the `<option>` but it's colliding with the dropdown menu, it's reading the quantity from the checkout and adds upp twice the amount in the dropdown.

**So what I am wondering is how do I seperate the jQuerys without changing classes.** Not sure if this is basic knowledge but I'm pretty tired and tried for a bit.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.quantity  :selected').change(function (event) {
        $quan = $(this);
        console.log($quan.parent().next()[0]);
        $quan.parent().next().find('.price').text(function () {
            return $quan.val() * parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10) + ' kr';
        });
            var total = 0;
            $('.price').each(function(k, v){
                total += parseFloat($(v).text(), 10); 
            });
            $('#total').text(total + ' kr')
    });
});
```

*Code written by Spokey.*

---

**NEW:** Updated into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tweath/EbkX2/) with the `HTML` and `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor your `.price` selectors with an element that is a parent of the list of items shown in the checkout but not a parent of the items in the cart, e.g.:

```
$('#checkout .price').each(...)
```

Comment: I'm having some troubles with the code on the checkout, the values doesn't work. The $total won't update and the quantity + price. http://jsfiddle.net/tweath/G4YcG/ @Alnitak